# How to get user ID from login name or username in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I've a website that is built on plain php but at the same time the database is shared with blogging site (wordpress). In my php site, I load wordpress through ./wp-load.php. In this case, everything that loads in the wordpress can be loaded in the php site too. I can retrieve everything except that I can't seem to get/retrieve the ID.

The reason why I want to retrieve ID is to show user description in the php site because description meta data is saved from the wordpress end only..
Here is how I tried to retrieved the ID. Though tried several times in many ways but didn't get through.

```
$u =  $page_username;

echo $u;  //here it retrieves the page owner username/ login name

$user = get_user_by('login','$u');// here is the failure. If I directly put username instead of variable $u, I can echo the ID.

if($user)
{
echo $user->ID;
}
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies, but if I can echo username, why not ID?.. Or if I can retrieve ID by directly putting username, why not from variable?

The end result I'd like to get is something like this:

```
 $u =  $page_username;//this displays the current username

 $user_id = $u->ID;

 echo get_user_meta ($user_id, 'description' , true )// If I directly put user Id, I can retrieve the user description..
```

Note: If there is a way to retrieve user meta by simply using username/ user_login, then solution to retrieving user_id is not required. I can directly then retrieve usermeta by simply using user_login which is already there..

I hope wordpress gurus will help me out in this.. I'm fairly new to wordpress, so it's taking lot's of time to get through even to a simple functions or those hooks and all..

Comment: $user = get_user_by('login',$u); instead of $user = get_user_by('login','$u');

Comment: None of them are solution. I already tried them.. I would need to see if I can get user meta data without retrieving ID.. is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

**These codes have been tested and are working properly:**

```
global $current_user; 

$user_ID   = $current_user->ID     ;
$user_info = get_userdata($user_ID);
$user_name = $user_info->user_login;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if ( !function_exists( 'get_user_by' ) ) { 
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php'; 
        }
    $user = get_user_by('login','$u');// here is the failure. If I directly put username instead of variable $u, I can echo the ID.

    if($user)
    {
    echo $user->ID;
    }
```

Comment: Since I load wp-core.php so I think I'd not need to load pluggable.php again.. Though tried with that but it makes no difference.. Can we get user meta data without actually needing to retrieve ID? with user_login/ username?

Answer (score 0):

User following :

$user = wp_get_current_user();

echo $user->roles[0];

Comment: It won't work.. How about getting user meta data by using username or user_login alone? is that possible with wp?